# The operator > is undefined for the argument type(s) java.util.Random, java.util.Random

Tags: java, random

I am trying to create a horse race betting game. I'm having trouble comparing the values of the horses to each other to see which one wins.

In the *if statement* I try to compare the value of horse1 with the value of horse2 and horse3. But I get the error of:
he operator > is undefined for the argument type(s) java.util.Random, java.util.Random

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
 import java.util.Random;
 public class RunHorseGame 
{

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

//variables
    String name;
    float bal;
    float bet;
    boolean nextRace;
    int raceChoice;
    int startRace;

    Random horse1 = new Random(100);
    Random horse2 = new Random(100);
    Random horse3 = new Random(100);
    Random horse4 = new Random(100);
    Random horse5 = new Random(100);
    Random horse6 = new Random(100);
    Random horse7 = new Random(100);

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

//welcome screen
    System.out.println("Welcome to Horse Racing!");
    System.out.println("Please enter your name:");
    name = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("welcome " + name + ", you have a balance of $200!");

//create loop to repeat races when one finishes (keep balance)
    nextRace = true;
    while (nextRace == true)
    {
        bal = 200;

//give race options
        System.out.println("Please select which race you would like to       enter:");
        System.out.println("Press 1 to enter: 3 horse race");
        System.out.println("Press 2 to enter: 5 horse race");
        System.out.println("Press 3 to enter: 7 horse race");

//create each race
//each horse has randomizer
//highest number wins race

        raceChoice = input.nextInt();
        switch(raceChoice)
        {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("You have entered the 3 horse race!");
                System.out.println("How much would you like to bet?");
                bet = input.nextFloat();
                System.out.println("You have bet " + bet + " dollars.");
                bal =- bet;
                System.out.println("Press 1 to start.");
                System.out.println("Press 2 to go back to race selection.");

                startRace = input.nextInt();
                switch(startRace)
                {
                case 1:


                    if(horse1 > horse2 && horse1 > horse3)
                    {

                    }

                    break;

                case 2:
                    nextRace = false;
                    break;
                }


                break;
            case 2:
                break;
            case 3:
                break;
            default:
                break;


        }

        nextRace = true;

    }
}
}
```

Comment: `Random horse1 = new Random(100);` **does not** make horse1 a random number up to 100 (which is what it looks like you are doing with it). You only need 1 `Random` object then horse1, horse2, etc would be ints or something and you assign them like `horse1 = myRandom.nextInt(100);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following:

```
    Random randomGenerator = new Random();

        int horse1 = randomGenerator.nextInt(100);
        int horse2 = randomGenerator.nextInt(100);
//and so on...
```

As (@ajb) rightly said that: A `Random` is not a random number. So when you are assigning horse a data type it should be `int` and not `Random` and then you should use the method of `Random` as shown above to get the desired random number.

Answer (score 4):

A `Random` is *not* a random number.  A `Random` is a random number **generator**.  So if you want to get numbers to compare, you have to use one of the methods in [`Random`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) to get the *generator* to generate a *number*.

Answer (score 2):

`Random` is a reference to the Random Number Generator and not to anything else. You don't need to create a new Random Number Generator for each horse.

Make one instance of `Random`:
`Random r = new Random()`

Then create the random chance of the horse:
`int horse = r.nextInt(100);`

Like so.